# HABTM - Error when saving: Method not found 'destroyed?' for Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have two Models: Teacher and Department related by has_and_belongs_to_many.

When I try to save or update_attributes from the Teacher I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'destroyed?' for #<Array:0x007ff2af0204f0>
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord 4.0.2/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:380:in 'save_has_one_association'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:188:in 'block in add_autosave_association_callbacks'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:383:in '_run__2528643575803035636__update__callbacks'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in 'run_callbacks'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:310:in `update_record'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:70:in `update_record'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:477:in `create_or_update'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__2528643575803035636__save__callbacks'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:106:in `save'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:32:in `save'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block (2 levels) in save'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
... 4 levels...
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:281:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:269:in `save'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:230:in `block in update'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:228:in `update'
from (irb):45
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/marcelomita/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

This error is preventing me to update my Teachers.

I don't know if this information is enogh, so if not ask me what you need. Thank you for your help and looking forward any answer.

### EDIT

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base

    #"validations are here"

    has_and_belongs_to_many :department

end

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_and_belongs_to_many :teacher

end
```

Comment: Please post your models' code and the controller code attempting the destroy.

Comment: I'm not trying to destroy anything. The destroyex? method return true if the object was destroyed but it doesn't aply for Arrays. I'm trying to figure out why its been called when I try to update a object. I'm editing my ask with my models.

Comment: In activerecord 4.0.2, line 188 of `lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb` is inside of `elsif reflection.macro == :has_one` -- any `:has_one` in either model? Please add your controller#update, too.

Comment: There is a has_one indeed. In the Department model I have belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Teacher" and on Teacher model I have has_one :department, foreign_key: 'manager_id'. I don't have any controller, I'm having this problem on rails console or on a ActiveAdmin page for the teacher model. Sorry for my delay in answering, I was busy in another project.